# How to display youtube videos in customer reviews

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, template, review

I want to display youtube videos in customer reviews.

Is there any possible to enable iframe in customer's review block? I want to modify the review module to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no default option to do this. The easiest way is create a static block to add the youtube iframe and then inject that static block to review page using a layout update. Follow the steps.

### 1. Crate static block

Create a static block from admin section. For this go to `CMS > Static blocks` and then click on `Add New` button. Then add your youtube iframe code inside the ***content*** section. The identifier of that block, let us name it as `review_youtube_iframe`.

### 2. Add Static Block via Layout Update

File : `app\design\frontend\[package]\[theme]\layout\local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <review_product_list>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="cms/block" name="review.youtube.iframe" as="youbute_iframe">
                <action method="setBlockId">
                    <block_id>review_youtube_iframe</block_id>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </review_product_list>
</layout>
```

The code simply add our static block inside `product.info` block which is wrapper block of review page.

### 3. Call our new block

The last step is to call our new block from the template of the block `product.info`. For this :

File : `app\design\frontend\[package]\[theme]\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`

```
<?php
    if (Mage::registry('productId')) {
        echo $this->getChildHtml('youbute_iframe');
    }
?>
```

Put this code inside that file in an appropriate place.

Now clear your cache and then load the page again.